# Are there pseudovectors in more than three dimensions?

Tags: vectors

Do pseudovectors only exist with vector product in $\mathbb R^3$ or do they appear in higher dimensions too?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424637/coordinate-free-definition-of-pseudotensors

Comment: Not really an answer, but in general, and actually already in three dimensions, it's better (in my opinion) to learn about the outer product and bivectors instead. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117139/what-exactly-are-pseudovectors-and-pseudoscalars-and-where-could-i-read-about-t, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264771/cross-product-and-pseudovector-confusion/264798.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark "pseudovectors and pseudoscalars are better understood as bivectors"... and, in turn, bivectors are better understood as differential 2-forms.

Comment: @Miguel: I don't quite agree about that. To me, a differential 2-form is a *bicovector field*, which is a more complicated object than just a bivector.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb R^n,$ given $n-1$ linearly independent vectors, you can construct a new vector that can be considered to be the cross product of those vectors. That is then a pseudovector.

If the $n-1$ vectors are $u^{(1)} = (u^{(1)}_1, \ldots, u^{(1)}_n), \ldots, u^{(n-1)} = (u^{(n-1)}_1, \ldots, u^{(n-1)}_n)$ then the pseudovector is given formally by
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
u^{(1)}_1 & \cdots & u^{(1)}_n \\
\vdots    &        & \vdots    \\
u^{(n-1)}_1 & \cdots & u^{(n-1)}_n \\
\hat e_1  & \cdots & \hat e_n
\end{vmatrix}
$$
where $\hat e_k$ is the unit vector in the direction of the $k$:th coordinate.